# Creating complex gradients in css or sass

Tags: css, sass

I am new to programming.

Is it possible to create a gradient like the background of [this design](https://dribbble.com/shots/15006543-Home-loan-landing-page-design) using sass or css? I want to place some colors in random places.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a bad question. The answer is yes, but I suppose that's not actually what you're asking. You should try again with a more comprehensive question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can by adding multiple gradient to you `background` property
[W3scool doc](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at 10% 20%, #FF000070 2%, transparent 40%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 70% 40%, #BADA5570 4%, transparent 10%),
    radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 80%, #BADA5570 7%, transparent 30%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Now we can customize this to make it.
I guess you can make all sorts of shapes with ellipse.
I only knew how to use the basics! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a similar effect might be achieved.

You can stack gradients by separating them with commas. The "white" color must be transparent so you can see through the uppermost gradients.

Take a look at this gradient:

```css
div {
  background: 
    radial-gradient(circle at 10px 30px, rgb(2, 0, 36) 0%, rgb(7, 6, 97) 31%, rgba(9, 9, 121, 0) 46%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 0) 100%),
    radial-gradient(circle at 600px 400px, rgb(200, 0, 36) 0%, rgb(200, 6, 97) 31%, rgba(9, 9, 121, 0) 46%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 0) 100%);
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the different practical uses!
I only knew the basic ones.
It's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Glassmorphism is the name of the effect.
Check this site [Glassmorphism](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/glassmorphism-design-effect-with-html-css/)

```css
.container{
  background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.25 );
  box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37 );
  backdrop-filter: blur( 10px );
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 4.0px );
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18 );
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  z-index:999;
}
.circle1{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:20px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius:50%;
  z-index:-1;
}

.circle2{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  right:20px;
  height:250px;
  width:250px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background:blue;
  border-radius:50%;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
  <div class="circle1"></div>
  <div class="circle2"></div>
```